# how can implemented two methods implement one after one need some time using uihandlers

Tags: android, refresh, handlers

i am implementing one chat messages related application in this main activity call one method and second method every ten seconds refreshing this method applied ui handler refreshing purpose both running at same time  my intension  is one method call some time and refresh applied second method call some time initally activity first time only how can implement time delay  in both methods

first method :

```
Handler handlerTimer = new Handler();

handlerTimer.postDelayed(new Runnable()
{
public void run()
{
handlerMessage("",0);

}}, 2000);
```

second method:

```
 class RefreshHandler extends Handler 
     {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg)
         {
            Main.this.updateUI();
         }
         public void sleep(long delayMillis) {
            this.removeMessages(0);
            if(isUpdateUI  )

          sendMessageDelayed(obtainMessage(0), delayMillis);
         }
         };
         private void updateUI()
              {
                handlerreferesh("",0);//this second method 

        }

        mRedrawHandler.sleep(10000);
         }
         }
```

first method initially call 2 sec after second refresh call some time how can implemented plaese forawrd some valuable suggestion  thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one thread with one handler for the first method and another thread with another handler for second method.

Comment: hi jinda please give me some example

Comment: i cannot understand exact scenario of your question.

Comment: this two methods running between time gap